# How to get next MonthDay (next Christmas) with java 8 time API?

Tags: time, java-8, java-time

Let's say I want to know how many days are until Christmas with a method that works any day of any year so next Christmas may be this year or next year that I don't know if it is a leap year or not.

I might calculate the next Christmas date and then calculate the days from now until then. I can represent Christmas Day as MonthDay.of(12, 25) but I can't find how that helps.

I found it is easy to calculate the date of next Monday this way:

```
    ZonedDateTime nextMonday = ZonedDateTime.now()
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

But I can't find any TemporalAdjuster to do the same with MonthDay.

Is there an easy way I didn't find?

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is not the right data type for your problem. Use `LocalDate` instead.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Is just a comment or it will help?

Comment: This will also help because it is a strong simplification. With `LocalDate` the suggestion of @assylias is 100% secure and working. With `ZonedDateTime` you also have to think about timezone-related stuff in depth. The nature of your problem does not require more than date precision. Making things overly complicated is just waist of resources.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Would you want to post an answer with that simplification? I can't understand how it helps the code to be simpler.

Comment: But @assylias has already posted the solution working with `LocalDate`, even shown an example how to apply the custom adjuster on an instance of `LocalDate`. You can of course also apply his adjuster on `LocalDate.now(timezone)`. I would accept his answer, and you get rid of any timezone stuff (with the exception of getting now()-instance of `LocalDate`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in temporal adjuster to go to the next "MonthDay" but you can build it yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MonthDay XMas = MonthDay.of(DECEMBER, 25);
  System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2014, DECEMBER, 5).with(nextMonthDay(XMas)));
  System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2014, DECEMBER, 26).with(nextMonthDay(XMas)));
}

public static TemporalAdjuster nextMonthDay(MonthDay monthDay) {
  return (temporal) -> {
    int day = temporal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = temporal.get(MONTH_OF_YEAR);
    int targetDay = monthDay.getDayOfMonth();
    int targetMonth = monthDay.getMonthValue();
    return MonthDay.of(month, day).isBefore(monthDay)
            ? temporal.with(MONTH_OF_YEAR, targetMonth).with(DAY_OF_MONTH, targetDay)
            : temporal.with(MONTH_OF_YEAR, targetMonth).with(DAY_OF_MONTH, targetDay).plus(1, YEARS);
}
```

Comment: I feared `plus` one year would add 365 days but I checked it and it is not the case so your adjuster should work. Thanks

Comment: @user270349 Yes it should take care of leap years properly. I have not tested it other than the 2 examples in the main, so you may want to run a few tests before using it though.

Comment: That's the problem with java.time not having this, that you have to test your code. I made my own TemporalAdjuster too.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following temporal adjusters:

```
public static TemporalAdjuster nextOrSame(MonthDay monthDay) {
    return temporal -> monthDay.adjustInto(temporal).plus(MonthDay.from(temporal).compareTo(monthDay) > 0 ? 1 : 0, YEARS);
}

public static TemporalAdjuster previousOrSame(MonthDay monthDay) {
    return temporal -> monthDay.adjustInto(temporal).minus(MonthDay.from(temporal).compareTo(monthDay) < 0 ? 1 : 0, YEARS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that creates a temporal adjuster given a MonthDay, just like the one of assylias but code is different. I think both work.

```
private static TemporalAdjuster nextMonthDayAdjuster(final MonthDay md) {
    return (Temporal d) -> {
        Function<Integer, Temporal> dateOnYear = year -> md.atYear(year).adjustInto(d);
        int year = d.get(ChronoField.YEAR);
        Temporal dateThatYear = dateOnYear.apply(year);
        if (d.until(dateThatYear, ChronoUnit.NANOS) > 0L) {
            return dateThatYear;
        } else {
            return dateOnYear.apply(year + 1);
        }
    };
}
```