# Java Autocomplete/Format Date from MM-DD input

Tags: java, date, autoformatting

Is there a way to auto complete a date in YYYY-MM-DD format where the input field would only require MM-DD.

The year would be the current year unless the month and day were in the past.

Example:

Input of "06-28"  would output 2017-06-28

and if the date was in the past,

Input "04-30" output 2018-04-30

The code would be written in HTML or Java

Thanks for the help and sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Sure, it sounds like it should be possible. It's not immediately obvious which language you're referring to, though. There's some confusion between the tags and title. PHP? Java? _JavaScript_? (Just guessing you _might_ mean JavaScript rather than Java based on the other tags.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I will edit the question tomorrow when my IT friend comes in to work. It is for a custom .php website form that he created for me. I'll re-ask the question or edit this one to be more concise.

Comment: How would you know what year to print if the date was in the past, and why are you printing a year in the future?

Comment: @ don't panic - the language would be HTML

Comment: @ Michael- I think I asked The original question in a confusing way but if the input month and date is prior to today's date the year to print would be the current year plus 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next MonthDay (next Christmas) with java 8 time API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215819/how-to-get-next-monthday-next-christmas-with-java-8-time-api).

Comment: Similar: [*Parsing date string (MM-dd) to java date in default year*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11493595/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) classes excel.

```
public static LocalDate autocomplete(String mmdd) {
    ZoneId clientTimeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(clientTimeZone);
    MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse(mmdd, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd"));
    Year y = Year.from(today);
    if (md.isBefore(MonthDay.from(today))) {
        // in the past; use next year
        y = y.plusYears(1);
    }
    return y.atMonthDay(md);
}
```

Please note the dependency on time zone. Think twice about which zone you should use.

If you need the result as a `String`, just use `toString()`.

Corner case: The method will accept `02-29` as valid input and will autocomplete into a date of February 28 if the chosen year is not a leap year. You may want to modify it to reject `02-29` unless next February has 29 days.

Comment: Can you show me how this code would work with an HTML input text box?

Comment: Not I, I’m afraid. @ZachHunter Too long ago this was my home field (I hope you didn’t mean JavaScript, because that’s different).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a simple function that checks the current date and based on that autocompletes the year?

Comment: @ Ethan Gills- writing the function is actually what I need help with. My buddy created me a HTML thing that uses a date picker but I will be inputting thousands of dates and the date picker is taking too long. Thanks