# Java DateTimeFormatter can't convert

Tags: java, datetime-format

```
    String str = "Jan 15";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd");
    LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

I keep getting this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Jan 15' could not be parsed at index 0  at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
>     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
>     at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)    at
>   com.mach5.T.main(T.java:17)

Could someone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113530/java-convert-string-date-to-month-name-year-mmm-yyyy

Comment: @FairPlay No, [your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113530/java-convert-string-date-to-month-name-year-mmm-yyyy) is not a duplicate. That other Question is about *generating* a year-month string from a full year-month-day value, while this Question is about *parsing* a month-day value without any year. I believe this Question here is indeed a duplicate, but I have not yet found a true original.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Parse as a `MonthDay` rather than `LocalDate`.

```
MonthDay.parse( 
    "Jan 15" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd" , Locale.US )
)
```

> --01-15

## `MonthDay`

Your input lacks a year, so it cannot be parsed as a `LocalDate`. Instead, parse as a `MonthDay`.

If you are parsing a string that represent a month-day, use a class that represents month-day values. That class would be [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd" , Locale.US ) ;
String input =  "Jan 15" ;
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> md.toString(): --01-15

That double-hyphen in the generated output string follows the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, indicating the year is unknown/omitted.

## `LocalDate`

You can assign a year if known.

```
LocalDate ld = md.atYear( 2017 ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2017-01-15

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/2NsaqQ).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("MMM dd")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getValue())
                                .toFormatter();
    LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a LocalDate without a year.

So either you need to add one.

```
        String str = "Jan 15 2016";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

Or you can modify the Formatter to fill in the current year, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523886/how-do-i-simply-parse-a-date-without-a-year-specified).

```
    String str = "Jan 15";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("MMM d")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getValue())
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);;
    LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated here, you are missing the year so as to be able to parse a LocaleDate.

[Java: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320971/java-unable-to-obtain-localdate-from-temporalaccessor)

Example: http://tpcg.io/dC93ex